# How to publish visual studio class library package to our internal Nuget server?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I created a class library package project in Visual Studio 2015. Also I created a unit test project in the solution. The next step is to reference the library in the test project.

However before doing that, I need to publish the class library to our internal Nuget server. I haven't found the materials online to do that.
Here is the project.json file.

```
    {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "description": "AuthenticationService Class Library",
      "authors": [ "me" ],
      "tags": [ "" ],
      "projectUrl": "",
      "licenseUrl": "",

      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
      }
    }
```

How?

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds?

Comment: Yes, we did it already. In Visual Studio 2013, we used gulp to push it. `return nuget.push('*.nupkg', {
            source: 'http://corporate.mycompany.com:81/nuget/Default',
            apiKey: 'sys_proget:blahblah'
        });`. However in Visual Studio 2015, how?

Answer (score 0):

I've got something working using the scripts section of project.json

```
"scripts": {
  "postpack": "%project:Directory%/../../build/batchcopy %project:Directory%/../../artifacts/bin/%project:Name%/%build:Configuration%/%project:Name%.%project:Version%.nupkg c:/packages"
}
```

This uses a copy of batchcopy.cmd I grabbed from the [DNX Github repository](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/build/batchcopy.cmd)

It appears to be working ok

Comment: Is it working for internal Nuget server?(Need url and api key) Could you put a sample code?

Comment: I'm just copying to an local folder for now, but the command is a standard command to run on the local machine, so any command should run

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I am not strong on DNX. Still no clue. Would you please add all  code of project.json? Elaborate it would be great.